# githubにプッシュできない。

Tags: git, github

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/###
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

このようなエラーが出ました。いつもならでないのですが、何をしたらいいのかよくわかりませんでした。
いつもと違うことをしたのは、githubでリポジトリ―を作るときにinitialize readmeをしたことです。
たぶんそれが原因だと思うのですが、どうしたらいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リモートの方がローカルよりコミットが進んでいるというエラーです。エラーメッセージに書かれているとおり、`git pull` をしてください。その際場合によっては手動でマージが必要になります。

もしそのリポジトリを作ったばかりなのであれば、ローカルのリポジトリ作成を `git clone` から始めるとスムーズでした。

Comment: pullした後に、pushすることができました。ありがとうございます。